# UseNpgsql not available in IServiceCollection in .NET Core

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to add (Postgresql) database connection. Here is a code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc();

     services.AddDbContext<ConexionWebApi>(options => {
     options.UseNpgsql("ConnectionString", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("WebAPISample"));
     });

}
```

But useNpgsql generates the following error:

> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseNpgsql' and no extension method 'UseNpgsl' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refence?)

I installed the followings NuGet packages:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools,    
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL,  
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design.
```

Should I install some other library?

Comment: Could be that you are missing a `using` statement which would allow for the use of the extension method

Comment: I reference with using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and continue the same error.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by adding

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Comment: Dang. It shouldn't be so hard to find the namespace of an extension method. Thanks