# 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for UseNpgsql()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am facing an issue while giving the connectionstring to get it connect to PostgreSQL through the `AddDbContext()` method in ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs

I'm getting this error while calling the function `options.UseNpgsql()` 
(see the image below).

I have seen other questions regarding this but those are for `usesqlserver()` and also they did not solve my problem.

[image]

Comment: Are you missing a using statement or an assembly reference? Did you read the error?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068696/usenpgsql-not-available-in-iservicecollection-in-net-core

Comment: Yes I have checked about that. I have added all the necessary using statements. Is there any other which I missed?

Comment: @DavidG Yes I have checked that answer and added those using but still the same error.

Comment: And do you have a reference to the [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/2.1.0-preview1) Nuget package?

Comment: Ohh Yeah.. I was missing the reference how come I dint see that. Thanks alot @DavidG it worked. :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Two things to check:

1. Are you missing a reference to the [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/2.1.0-preview1)  Nuget package?
2. Are you missing the correct import. The `UseNpgsql()` extension method is in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace which means you should have this line:

   ```
   using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
   ```

Comment: I have done both of these things but still having the same issue... I'm guessing it has to do with using version 5.X of these? EDIT: Solved by saving changes to NuGet packages (you can do this by restarting visual studio)

Comment: For those of you who are too quick to look: this is the Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore nuget package, not the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package that you need to add...

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I solve the problem when I install the  Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore but i didn't even import it into the code. weird.

Answer (score 9):

**I solved this problem by checking that all these 3 packages are intalled:**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore   
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

and the third one was the problem for my application. It was not installed.
Don't forget to add reference for any of these packages when needed in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the following package:
NuGet\Install-Package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime -Version 8.0.0-preview.4